# (Higher/upper/above) and (below/under/lower) the sea level

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Which construction is more correct when in comes to comparing the height of a specific place to the sea level?

> - This place is 100 feet **above** the sea level.
> - This place is 100 feet **higher than** the sea level.
> - This place is 100 feet **upper than** the sea level.

and

> - This place is 100 feet **below** the sea level.
> - This place is 100 feet **lower than** the sea level.
> - This place is 100 feet **under** the sea level.

Which pair words do you normally use in such a context?

Answer (score 1):

No.3 is completely wrong. All three should probably drop `the`, it is syntactically correct, but not normally used.

No.1 is the most likely to be used in normal speech, but No.2 is okay.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by #1 and #2 @Mike Brockington? Do you mean that the **"above/below"** version is the most correct one and the **"higher than/lower than"** construction works too, but the **"above/below"** version is the most common and correct one? Is it what you meant?